# Extract X.509 certificate from this p12 file by it's alias.by using forge

Tags: javascript, java, security, encryption, x509

There is Java's security api's, which is able to extract X.509 certificate from this p12 file by it's alias.

```
X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
```

How it is possible to extract X.509 certificate from p12 file by using forge?

Comment: What is "forge"?

Comment: is a javascript library

Comment: As mentioned, Java is not Javascript, so can you please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly? Tag it with the correct tags, and explain a) what you need to do, b) what you did, c) why that didn't work, and d) what you tried so far

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation for reading [PKCS12 content using forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs12)? There's a detailed example for the same.